# dispalytag table align vertically

Tags: jsp, struts

```
    <table width="100%" >

    <tr>

    <td>
        <%
            int rowCount1 = 0;
            %>
             <display:table id="quotationCreationDetss" name="quotationCreationDetss" sort="page"
            pagesize="10" export="false"
             class="listingBorder">
            <%
                String rowClass = "";
                    if (rowCount1 % 2 == 0) {
                        rowClass = "evenRow";
                    } else {
                        rowClass = "oddRow";
                    }
            %>

            <display:column  property="purch_req_no" title="Enq No" headerClass="headerRow" class='<%=rowClass%>'  />
            <display:column property="vendor_name" title="Vendor Name"  headerClass="headerRow"  class='<%=rowClass%>'> </display:column>
            <display:column property="vendor_sl_no" headerClass="hidden"  class="hidden" /> 
            <display:column property="total_amount"  title="Total" headerClass="headerRow"  class='<%=rowClass%>'></display:column>

            <%-- <display:column   headerClass="headerRow" title ="Details" class='<%=rowClass%>'>
            <a href="detailsvendor?detail_ven_sl_no=${quotationCreationDetss.vendor_sl_no}" >Details </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </display:column> --%>

            <display:column   headerClass="headerRow" title ="Details" class='<%=rowClass%>'>
                <a href='#' class='click' onclick="detlvendor(${quotationCreationDetss.vendor_sl_no})">detials</a> <br/>
            </display:column>

            <%
                rowCount1++;
            %>
            <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
        </display:table>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

output

```
Enq No  Vendor Name Total   
1181    ABC CORP    2520.0  
1181    DELL        5020.0
```

i  want output like this

```
VendorName   ABC CROP   DELL
Toal         2520       5020
```

help to get output like this.

Comment: Do you think its easy to work with Scriplet and HTML together. Why not use JSTL or EL?

Comment: @Braj Scriptlets not important here and could be removed.

Comment: any other way to create table like this .